What is the purpose of this board contact - see photo
I am trying to learn electronics as a hobbyist and my first project is to fix my shaver.  I notice when I dis-assemble the shaver that there is a piece of metal in the bottom plastic 'container' that connects to 2 contact points on the circuit board of the shaver.  This is the piece of metal:

And on the shaver circuit board are these contacts:

The piece of metal does line up with those contacts on the bottom of the circuit board.  The metal  is on top of a thick block of plastic.  Is the purpose of the metal contact to ensure that the shaver can only work when the circuit board is connected into the bottom plastic part?  Just trying to figure out what this is for?
And presumably if that is the case I can only test it if I insert the circuit board into the plastic bottom?
What is the purpose of this contact?  Is my reasoning correct?
For anyone's interest this is a Babyliss Pro shaver.

There is grease on the contacts. Are they linked to a user accessible control? Do they slide? They could simply be the power-on switch.

Yes it slides and is linked to power on slider, didn't notice that.

It's a slide switch. The actuator half of the switch is in the enclosure and the contact half is no the PCB.
